# Inserting Javascript into ASP.Net page

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-4.5

I have the code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function validateLength(objectSource, args) {
        var a = document.getElementById('<%=txtUserName.ClientID%>').value;
        args.IsValid = (a.length >= 5 && a.length <= 10);
    }
</script>
```

Which I have in my ASP.NET page.

This works fines. Will validate a textbox to make sure it is between a certain length.

However I am trying to tidy up my page's code. So decided to put this little function into a separate javascript file.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/MyJS.js">
</script>
```

Page loads fine and then when the validation comes around it fails. I am guessing it cannot access the textbox( txtUserName).

My question is: How can I get this to work?

I get the error message

```
0x800a138f - Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to get value of the property 'value': object is null or undefined
```

when the javascript fires

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript" src"Scripts/MyJS.js">` -> `<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/MyJS.js">`

Comment: yeah you forgot an = by src

Comment: @messerbill that was me forgetting while typing the code here. In my actual code there is an =

Comment: `document.getElementById('<%=txtUserName.ClientID%>')` is not found / existent on your page. Have you spelled it correctly?

Comment: @messerbill the code works fine when the script is in the page itself. But when loading from a .js file it cannot find it

Comment: You will have to set a variable to the global scope in the page to the value of the ClientID that the script can then use.

Comment: you should add alert(a) to check the value at that moment.

Comment: @TonyWu I've been doing that, always comes back as null. Going to try solutions below

Comment: @Sam Okay, good luck.

Comment: @Sam What about the value of document.getElementById('<%=txtUserName.ClientID%>') ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you include a javascript file, the part of code

```
<%=txtUserName.ClientID%>
```

isn't rendered.

You have to change the javascript function in two ways
Fixing the name of the control

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function validateLength(objectSource, args) {
        var a = document.getElementById('txtUserName').value;
        args.IsValid = (a.length >= 5 && a.length <= 10);
    }
</script>
```

or adding a parameter

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function validateLength(objectSource, args, nameOfControl) {
        var a = document.getElementById(nameOfControl).value;
        args.IsValid = (a.length >= 5 && a.length <= 10);
    }
</script>
```

then you can call the function from your page and the parameter nameOfControl could be

```
<%=txtUserName.ClientID%>
```

for example

```
validateLength(objectSource, args, <%=txtUserName.ClientID%>)
```

Comment: Adding the element name worked great. Thank you. I knew it would be something simple.

Answer (score 2):

The `<%=txtUserName.ClientID%>` runs in context of your page. That will not work in a separate .js file.
Separate .js files won't run any asp.net code.
You could do something like:

**JS file:**

```
function validateLength(objectSource, args) {
    var a = document.getElementById(window.myValidatorId).value;
    args.IsValid = (a.length >= 5 && a.length <= 10);
}
```

**ASP**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.myValidatorId = '<%=txtUserName.ClientID%>';
</script>
```

Or perhaps read the id from a hidden input field on the page.

Comment: but saving data in the browser is not beautiful, i would send it as a param via a normal function